# OSX: Affix window to not move on spaces switch

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, mac, spaces

Is there an option, or external program that anyone knows of that would allow me to set window to always stay in the same position on every one of my 4 spaces / not move when I switch.

Like I want VLC player to not move so I watch a movie, but switch spaces between other applications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open System Preferences > Exposé & Spaces, click the "+" under the listbox of Application Space assignments, select your application (which must be running), then click in the **Space** column for the newly-added application entry where it says "Space 1"; "Every Space" appears at the top of the dropdown list.